# How to enable ASP.Net panel when it is disabled on page load?

Tags: asp.net, panel

I have code which disable ASP.NET Panel on Page_Load:

```
uiPnlDetails.Enabled = False;
```

Then I have grid which if the row clicked it will raise event to enable it back.  The event is raised successfully, because I can make a breakpoint somewhere in the block, and statement which enabling the panel is also successfully called.  I found the uiPnlDetail.Enabled value in window Watch is set to True.

But the result on page:

```
<div disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_MainContent_uiPnlDetails">
```

So everything inside the div is disabled.  I already checked all the code, but no code is set the panel to disable again after I enabled it.

How can I debug this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have any UpdatePanel on the page?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve out your problem

```
If(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
uiPnlDetails.Enabled = False;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable the Panel in an if block which checks the postback like this

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  uiPnlDetails.Enabled = False;
}
```

in your `Page_Load` method.

Every time a postback occurs Page_Load method is called and if you don't check for the above condition you will always end up with `uiPnlDetails.Enabled = False;`.

That div you mention is just your rendered panel, nothing special.Panels are rendered as divs by browsers.

Comment: I already did that too.  But again, if it is not postback (first time page loaded), disabling panel will make it disable forever, even if there is some code on postback behaviour which enable it.

Comment: @saber35 that doesn't seem like an ordinary problem to me can you add your code to your question?And about that update panel, it could be the reason, can you try it without it?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to verify that you check that `Page.IsPostBack == false` in your page load code, so it doesn't run when the event is fired.

Answer (score 1):

When ever `UpdatePanel` is updated, page is posted back on server. In Asp.Net you can identify it using `Page.IsPostBack` which is a `boolean`. Now on page load check if `IsPostBack` is `false` then only set `uiPnlDetails.Enabled = False;`

In your case row clicked event is posting the page, this you will need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

> One liner

- If you have one update panel in your page, Then make sure all controls that are suppose to update after postback should be in update panel too.

> What I mean here is

- It might be case that panel you are enabling after click is outside updatepanel. So wrap that `<asp.panel>` inside an `<asp.UpdatePanel>` and make sure that UpdateMode="Always".

Hope this helps.